# Customize Drill up Button in Vaadin Charts

Tags: vaadin, vaadin7

Is there any way to customize the drill up button in Vaadin Charts? I know how to change the style

```
conf.getDrilldown().getDrillUpButton().setTheme(drillUpButtonTheme);
```

but how can I change the text?

Comment: What is the drill down button? Is it add-on or what?

Comment: Sorry, I meant Vaadin Charts not Vaadin, I edited the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it this way:

```
Lang lang = new Lang();
lang.setDrillUpText("your text here");
ChartOptions.get().setLang(lang);
```

Corresponding Highcharts doc: http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#lang.drillUpText